# Display the similar posts to a custom post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post  type 'events'. On 'single-events.php ' i want to display the similar posts related to this .
I am using the following code but the problem is it is also displaying the current post. How do i get rid of current post, please help me out.

```
 <?php
                   $args = array( 'post_type'=>'events',
                  'tax_query' => array(

                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'Event type',
                      'field' => 'slug',
                      'terms' => $type,
                    )
                  )
                );
                $postslist = get_posts( $args );


              ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make a `if`condition into your loop which asks for the id of the post not to be the same of the current post.